# What is good practice for freeing memory when a function copies a pointer-passed argument?

Tags: c, memory-management

If a function copies the contents of a pointer-passed argument so as to make the data it contains only accessible "internally", but this parameter is filled with the call of a function allocating the elements on the heap and returning a pointer to them, this will cause a memory leak because no variable will have been assigned to the expression sent. See this example:

```
struct my_struct_s
{
    char *msg;
};

struct my_struct_s *make_struct(char *msg)
{
    struct my_struct_s *res = malloc(sizeof *res);
    if (res == NULL)
        return NULL;

    res->msg = strdup(msg); // I make a copy
    if (res->msg == NULL)
    {
        free(res);
        return NULL;
    }
    return res;
}

void release(struct my_struct_s **my_struct)
{
    if (*my_struct == NULL)
        return;
    free((*my_struct)->msg);
    free(*my_struct);
}

int main()
{
    // char *str = strdup("Hello, world!");
    // struct my_struct_s *my_struct = make_struct(str);
    struct my_struct_s *my_struct = make_struct(strdup("Hello, world!"));
    release(&my_struct);
    // free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

The commented code presents a version of this program without a memory leak (I think), because we have a variable (`str`) that can later be accessed to be released, while the uncommented code will therefore cause a memory leak, because we don't have control over the allocated memory.

The field `msg` is accessible because the body of the structure is declared here in the same file, but suppose it is defined in an implementation file, where it will therefore not be accessible from the outside without going through a function.

In this kind of situation, what are the best practices to have in order to avoid memory leaks? Create a variable to be released afterwards, as in commented code, or not making a copy in the function, potentially making the code more complicated to manipulate?

Comment: best practice is to comment you code as much as possible and especially the function parameters and return value, using `const` on parameters that are not supposed to be destroyed is also good practice. it is all about showing intent and being consistent

Comment: `strdup("Hello, world!")` creates a memory leak since `msg` is never freed  in `make_struct()` and the pointer is lost in `main()` (it will be freed on exit, but if looking at your program in a memory use/error check program like `valgrind` it will still be shown as "in-use"). There is no need to use a pointer-to-pointer as the parameter for `release()`, simply passing a pointer is sufficient to `free` the memory.

Comment: You don't have to make a copy of the string in your case. Just pass the string literal directly. make_struct("Hello, world!")

Comment: @tstanisl That copy was trivial, it was just for the sake of example. Imagine a more complex type of data that is allocated on the heap, whose pointer is returned from a function like `strdup`does.

Comment: I see, thank you for your advice.

Comment: C language does not offer means of passing the ownership of objects (like C++'s unique_ptr). The good practice is to copy all relevant data when creating new object. Other was around is using reference counters. Just increment it for object that you plan to share the ownership.